# Why is jest using ts-jest touching my js files

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm using jest for the first time in conjunction with ts-jest and I can't understand the nature of the error that occurs:

```bash
$ jest
 FAIL  src/lib/Core/Storage/JsonStorage.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /app/src/lib/Core/Storage/JsonStorage.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import fs from 'fs/promises'
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import fs from 'fs/promises'
    > 2 | import JsonStorage from './JsonStorage'
        | ^
      3 | import type IStorage from './IStorage'
      4 |
      5 | jest.mock('fs/promises')

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1495:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/lib/Core/Storage/JsonStorage.test.ts:2:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.235 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Here is an example of the test I want to perform:

```js
import fs from 'fs/promises'
import JsonStorage from './JsonStorage'
import type IStorage from './IStorage'

jest.mock('fs/promises')

describe('JsonStorage', () => {
  let storage: IStorage<object>

  beforeEach(() => {
    storage = new JsonStorage('')

    jest.resetAllMocks()
  })

  test('Storage json object to file', async () => {
    fs.writeFile = jest.fn()

    const data = {
      one: 'one',
      two: 'two',
    }
    const pathname = './mokefile.json'
    const json = '{"one":"one","two":"two"}'

    await storage.save(pathname, data)

    expect(fs.writeFile).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(fs.writeFile).toHaveBeenCalledWith(pathname, json, 'utf8')
  })
})
```

and here is my code that I am testing:

```js
import fs from 'fs/promises'
import type IStorage from './IStorage'

export default class JsonStorage<T = object> implements IStorage<T> {
  constructor(private _space: string) {}

  async save(pathname: string, data: T) {
    const json = JSON.stringify(data, null, this._space)

    await fs.writeFile(pathname, json, 'utf8')
  }
}
```

my tsconfig:

```json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node18/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2022",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@App/*": ["./src/lib/*"],
      "@config/*": ["./src/config/*"]
    },
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "watchOptions": {
    "watchFile": "useFsEvents",
    "watchDirectory": "useFsEvents",
    "fallbackPolling": "dynamicPriority",
    "synchronousWatchDirectory": true,
    "excludeDirectories": ["node_modules"]
  },
  "include": ["src", "bin", "index.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "./**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

my jest.config.ts

```js
import { type JestConfigWithTsJest, pathsToModuleNameMapper } from 'ts-jest'
import { compilerOptions } from './tsconfig.json'

type ModuleNameMapper = Required<JestConfigWithTsJest>['moduleNameMapper']

const moduleNameMapper = pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths) as ModuleNameMapper

const jestConfig: JestConfigWithTsJest = {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': [
      'ts-jest',
      {
        useESM: true,
        isolatedModules: true,
        tsconfig: 'tsconfig.jest.json',
      },
    ],
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '^.+\\.jsx?$',
  ],
  modulePaths: [compilerOptions.baseUrl],
  moduleNameMapper,
}

export default jestConfig
```

Now for more information - `tsc` compiles the files to the same place where the .ts files are located only, and this is the problem, judging by the error term -`/app/src/lib/Core/Storage/JsonStorage.js:1`, for some reason, it is imported into the test js file, not the original one that I need on typescript, and as I understood this error could be avoided using babel something like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  // other config options...
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
    // add this line:
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
  }
};
```

but I don't want to connect babel, I need to work with my ts files and it seems to me that jest just doesn't see ts files, how to direct it, using the ts version, not js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the loading order of modules through extensions:

```js
import { compilerOptions } from './tsconfig.json'

type ModuleNameMapper = Required<JestConfigWithTsJest>['moduleNameMapper']

const moduleNameMapper = pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths) as ModuleNameMapper

const jestConfig: JestConfigWithTsJest = {
  ...
  // This is a row that needs to be changed, it is by default ["js", "mjs", "cjs", "jsx", "ts", "tsx", "json", "node"]
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js', 'json', 'node'],
  ...
}

export default jestConfig
```